# Disabling a certain webgl plug-in (or possibly feature) in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

At some time in the past I enabled a flag- or installed a plugin, I'm not sure which- that looks like this:

[image: what is this thing called?]

It's lovely to have when I'm doing WebGL work, but when I'm not it takes up quite a bit of visible space on my 13 inch screen.

I would like to switch it off, but I can't for the life of me remember what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind- it's in the 'rendering' tab of dev tools- option is 'Show FPS meter'